# Data transfer preloader or alert box in Delphi

Tags: delphi, sql-server-express

I have a software that uses a SQL Server express database. When the software runs local the data is loaded fast however when I run it remote there is always some delay populating grids etc..etc..

I'm looking to make a some kind of preloader or an alert box that appears with a bar indicating that data is being loaded into the software and prevent the user from clicking on the form.

Can you guys point me to a tutorial or if you can give just a general idea how to accomplish that ?

Comment: You should really make some attempt at solving this issue yourself before posting a question on here. The logical thing to do is to have your data retrieval done in a separate thread that you spawn on application start up. If the user is required to log on, you can be loading the data in background while they're typing in a username and password.

Comment: Dad, your solution will not work. I have about 30 forms each one is using multiple data controls communicating back and forth with the server..I just need to indicate if data is currently loading. Also Im not looking for a solution but a direction I will do it myself.

Comment: The cursor with that little SQL indicates that something is happening with a dataset derived control, doesn't it ?

Comment: It does but I want to prevent the user from manipulating data before its completely loaded. Like a msgbox that says "Data loading"..

Comment: If you're put off a solution because you have 30 forms in your application, I would suggest there is something fundamentally wrong with your application design.

Comment: Nope the app is just fine..your solution is no good, unless you think I should preload clinical data on more than a 1000 patients ? See even if you pull a single patient record that will contain numerous lab results by day and time, xrays, clnical notes..etc..etc. One needs to pull only the data that is needed and I want to make sure that the physicians can work with the form only if the data is completely loaded. Also want to make sure that the data is being sent completely before the form is closed..see my point. So far I have no issues, but with multiple users and large volumes..

Comment: if you know when the form is ready - then put everything in a frame /or panel/ and disable the frame. When everything is ready just enable it.

Comment: ..that is good..but how do I know that the data is done loading ?

Comment: "how do I know that the data is done loading" I'm puzzled that you should ask that, if you've got 30 forms, because you surely know by now: A call to TDataSet.Open does not return until the operation is completed, so all you need do is to open the datasets needed to view a given patient's data before you show the needed forms. That way no possibility of users fiddling with data before its completely loaded ever arises.

Comment: "TDataSet.Open does not return until the operation is completed" this is what I was not sure of..if that is the case then my question is really obsolete. BTW Im not a professional programmer but a physician with a hobby.. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget optimisations like background threads and async dataset loading until you've got the basic workflow of your app correct.  Generally, the thing to do with datasets is to open the minimum number necessary to permit the current user operation, and open others, e.g. needed for drilling down into a selected patient's details only as needed.  In each case you open the dataset before the related form is shown; that way, the opportunity for the user to try working with only partially loaded data never arises.

So in a situation like this apparently is, where the user browses a collection of patients
in a Patients table, start out with a form containing a DBGrid connected to a dataset component
that delivers the Patient rows.  Don't show the form until after you've opened the Patients table, in read-only mode.  And don't open any other datasets yet.

Presumably there's a collection of patient detail tables that need to be opened to show the data of a given  patient on one or more forms - I imagine there might be a top-level Patient's ID Details form,
and maybe a number of drill-down ones which can be invoked from it.  Again, don't show this form(s) until the tables needed to supply the patient data are open.  The easiest way to make the user aware that they should wait while something completes
is to surround the code involved with something like this:

```
  Screen.Cursor := crSqlWait;
  Screen.activeForm.Update;  // refreshes the current form to ensure 
  //  the cursor gets updated on-screen

  // Open the patient details table(s) and create the related form(s) here

  Screen.Cursor := crDefault;

  //  Now, show whichever is the principal patient detail form
```

Once the user has finished with a patient's details, close the form(s) that were opened to do it and close the related datasets.

Sql Server and Delphi are quite capable of populating a top-level DBGrid with outline info for several thousand patients with hardly any perceptible delay, as long as the data is all retrieved into one dataset (e.g. an AdoQuery) using one SQL SELECT statement. **Don't** take my word for it, **try** it with your own data.  If it seems to slow, you're doing something wrong.

The key is not to attempt to do more than you need to at the time.  As I've explained, only retrieve patient-specific data once the user has selected a top-level patient record to work on.  Until the app knows which patient the user is working one, it's pointless trying to retrieve patient-specific data of the type you mentioned in comments and would only slow down the app and generate needless network traffic.

Comment: Yes thank you..this is what I will work on. So far the app works like a charm, even remotely. I have 100 pt already logged in and no issue whatsoever. I have never worked with large databases and may be Im looking for issues when there are none. Thank you.